# How to parse HTML string using JSON.parse() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, parsing

I have an ASP.NET MVC application returning a JSON string to the VIEW.

```
// Parsing the model returned on the VIEW
var jsonString = '@Html.Raw(Model.ToJson())';
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

The problem is that I am not able to parse because the **jsonString** contains characters such as "\" and "'".

```
//Sample string
{ "description" : "<p>Sample<span style=\"color: #ff6600;\"> Text</span></strong></p>" }
```

Answer (score 5):

JSON is valid JavaScript, so you can just do this:

```
var jsonObj = @Html.Raw(Model.ToJson());
```

FYI, the reason the JSON parsing is failing is because the although the `"` are escaped with `\` to make it valid JSON, the backslashes themselves need escaping in the string for them to be seen by the JSON parser. Compare:

```
JSON.parse('"quote: \""');  // error: unexpected string
JSON.parse('"quote: \\""'); // 'quote: "'
```

This example should also clarify what's happening to the backslashes:

```
var unescaped = '\"', escaped = '\\"';

console.log(unescaped, unescaped.length); // '"',  1
console.log(escaped, escaped.length);     // '\"', 2
```

Comment: Your answer explains everything. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a valid Javascript string, you need to escape backslashes and apostrophes:

```
var jsonString = '@Html.Raw(Model.ToJson().Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("'", "\\'"))';
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(your html string here);
```

Comment: The OP was asking for a solution in JavaScript, not .net